# Transit Visa in South Korea for Uzbekistan Passport Holder?

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, south-korea, uzbek-citizens

I am a Uzbek student in China and I want to come back to Uzbekistan via flights from Shanghai to Seoul (Incheon) and Seoul (Incheon) to Tashkent. Transit time is 19-20 hours; do I need a transit visa for South Korea?

Please give me official references. Thanks.

Comment: The answer will depend upon your nationality. What is it?

Comment: I am from Uzbekistan

Answer (score 5):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Visa required, except for Passengers
>   transiting through Seoul (ICN) with a confirmed onward ticket for a
>   flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the
>   international transit area of the airport and have documents required
>   for the next destination.

So no, you don't need a visa.