# Interpreting Timatic report

Tags: timatic

I began to draft an answer to [this Travel:SE question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152821/transit-in-korea-for-uzbekistan) about the OP's need for a transit visa. The facts weren't complicated: Uzbeki national, going to school in China, with a transit in Seoul (ICN) on the way home. This looked like an easy referral to Timatic.

This data returned this Timatic report. Because my question here is an interpretation issue, I think it shouldn't be indexed for the underlying site; here's a screenshot:

[image]

The info at the top under "Normal Passports" says TWOV is OK for this passport holder transiting through ICN with a confirmed ticket for a flight leaving for a third country within 24 hours. We've all seen these sorts of conditions before.

Later down the page, however, it says "This TWOV facility does not apply at Seoul (ICN)."

I've not seen the exception-at-the-bottom conflict with the (satisfied) conditions at the top under TWOV.

How should this be interpreted?

EDIT: The same issue arises when querying Timatic about [this itinerary](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152888/connecting-filight-long-layover-in-korea): Philipines citizen traveling Manila > ICN > Brazil. This suggests the issue may be localized to Timatic's memorized response when ICN is presented as a Transit point.

Comment: I would put this on the main site.  I don't know whether there's an opposite to "meta," but there should be, and this question is more that than it is meta.  That is, it's more about travel than it is about [main].

Answer (score 5):

The bullet point excepting ICN applies to the *second* TWOV facility, the one that begins "Visa required, except for passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country on the same calendar day."  This TWOV facility applies everywhere except ICN, while the first TWOV facility applies at ICN.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. The issue was strikingly difficult for me to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

At Seoul (ICN) you can transit for up to 24 hours, because the transit area remains open overnight. Other airports close their transit areas at night, so you can only transit within the same day there.